# What is killing me?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I was travelling a corner of Novigrad seeking a new location on the map, where I reached a weird tree, and any time I got close to it I simply dropped dead. From full health of 6000+ vitality to 0 instantly. No fall. No monsters. No fight. Just walking.

Here is a video: 
https://www.facebook.com/yahavbr/videos/vb.670059072/10154340184989073

Screenshot from the video:

[image]

Here is picture of the location on the map:

[image]

And in the world's map:

[image]

Is this a bug, if so is there a way to bypass it? I tried about 5 times from different locations before giving up, as [each  time means long minutes of loading](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240572/is-this-possible-to-load-a-saved-game-faster).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get there yet. I wasn't aware there was a death wall, but you'll visit that location later in the game.

Comment: Hmm... Any reference? I don't mind spoilers. (Just a link no need to quote as to not spoil to everyone.) Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's Bald Mountain. It is a very late story related area, so looking it up will lead to massive spoilers.

Comment: also related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221944/how-can-i-reach-the-massive-tree-in-the-south-near-bald-mountain

Comment: Just finished the related quest. :)